# Render DT::datatable in browser using flexdashboard with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to build an interactive table in flexdashboard with Shiny. The following reprex displays the table in the Rstudio viewer but the CSV button does not work. When attempting to open in a local browser the table is not displayed.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}    
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

df <- data_frame(
  x = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "c", "b", "a"),
  y = c(1, 6, 7, 5, 9, 3, 8, 2),
  z = c("one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "three", "one", "two")
)

```

Column {data-width=200 .sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("x_input", label = "Select x Value",
            choices = c("All", unique(as.character(df$x))), selected = "All")

roster_input <- reactive({
  if (input$x_input=="All"){
  df
  }else{
  df %>% 
    filter(x==input$x_input)}
})

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(
    roster_input(),
    rownames = FALSE, 
    filter = "top",
    extensions = c('Buttons', 'Scroller'),
    options = list(
      dom = 'Blfrtip',
      buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
      deferRender = T,
  scrollY = '400px',
  scroller = TRUE))})
```
````

What am I missing to make this work in my local browser?

Comment: `renderDataTable` is from the `shiny` package. I would try to use `renderDT` instead (or `DT::renderDataTable`).

Comment: Unfortunately that produces the same result.